# Kendo numberictextbox read value

Tags: kendo-ui

Hi I have the following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(e =>e.Cost)        
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 80px;height: 15px;font-size: 11px;" })
.Format("{0:c}")
.Deferred()
.Decimals(2)
.Enable(true)
Spinners(false))
```

I would like to know how I can read the value entered.  I have tried this:

```
alert($('#Cost').data('kendoNumericTextBox').value());
```

but I received this error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Can you please help?  Thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling the script? The error says `$('#Cost')` doesn't exists in DOM **or** the widget isn't created yet.

Comment: I put my script at the bottom of the page.  I noticed that if I removed the .Deferred then I was able to read the value.  Is this the issue?

Comment: [Read this doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/fundamentals#deferred-initialization), I think it is your case.

Comment: Can you please tell me another way to validate Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor?  The reason why I added Deferred in order the validation to work.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you wrap your widget initialization code in a document.ready event ?